# Catching Errors Inside Multiple .all() Calls

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I've been wrapping my head around promises trying to implement a simple working example that matches what I'm trying to do in my application.

I've got it 85% down, I'm just not sure if this would actually catch errors if it were to happen inside the subsequent `.all()` calls.  I thought about using a `.catch()` to grab the errors, but various examples seemed to use `.done()` instead.

Am I catching all the errors that could happen in this example?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var UUID = require('node-uuid');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

var innerArray = function() {
  return [
    {  type: "thing", id: UUID.v4()  },
    {  type: "thang", id: UUID.v4()  },
    {  type: "thing", id: UUID.v4()  },
    {  type: "thang", id: UUID.v4()  }
  ];
};

var outerArray = [
  innerArray(),
  innerArray(),
  innerArray(),
  innerArray()
];

fs.readdirAsync('dump')
  .then(function(files) {
    return files.map(function(file) {
      return fs.unlinkAsync('dump/' + file);
    });
  })
  .then(function(stuff) {
    return Promise.all(outerArray.map(function(inArr) {
      return Promise.all(inArr.map(function(item, itemIndex) {
        return fs.writeFileAsync( 'dump/' + item.id, JSON.stringify(item));
      }));
    }));
  }).done(function(donezo) {
    console.log('Done!');
  }, function(e) {
    throw e;
  });
```

Sorry to post a code dump and ask "does this work?"  The code works, I'm just unsure of if it would catch an error if it were to happen at some point in the flow.

Comment: Yes, although making that last `.done` is redundant since Bluebird will find all the errors for you, and also - you can chain, you don't have to nest them.

Comment: Also, you can use `Promise.map(arr, fn` instead of `Promise.all(arr.map(fn`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm only throwing an error here because it's a test script to understand how promises work.  Normally I'd return the error back up to where the method in question is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes any error from anywhere would propagate to the done error handler but that error hander is unnecessary if you are just throwing the error. The only reason to have error handler is UI messages or very customized log (if writing stack traces redirected from stderr to a file is not enough)

Other than that I would actually write it as:

```
fs.readdirAsync('dump').map(function(file) {
  return fs.unlinkAsync('dump/' + file);
}).then(function() {
  return Promise.map(outerArray, function(inArr) {
    return Promise.map(inArr, function(item, itemIndex) {
      return fs.writeFileAsync( 'dump/' + item.id, JSON.stringify(item));
    });
  });
}).then(function() {
  console.log('Done!');
});
```

Comment: I'm only throwing an error because this is something I wrote to understand Promises (not something I would do in production code).  Normally the error gets passed back and is handled intelligently.  Thanks for the cleaner code, I thought my example was pretty verbose.